# Javascript memory leak in recursive polling method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, memory-leaks

*Actual problem that needs solved: I'm working on a large application, the initial release of which was about two years ago.  We're now adding a new page to the application, and noticing some odd behavior.  The new screen is going to be an "always-on" status screen, meaning it is the default screen in the app and the dedicated pc the app runs on will always display it by default.  After a certain amount of time (only a few minutes on IE, usually much longer on Chrome) things start misbehaving.  First, the animation of the scrolling messages (if any) becomes choppy and slow, eventually to the point that they appear to move about 1 pixel/second.  The choppiness begins in minutes in IE on the machines we use, and within a couple of hours will be slowed to a crawl.  By that time, the other odd behavior has started: the browser itself will be slow to react.  There is a menu/login button on this screen, and there is a delay of 3-4 seconds before anything happens when it is clicked.  Other visual elements have a similar delay before updating, even though they have no interaction with the user.*

I and others on the team have spent several days looking at everything on this page, and **think we have the cause narrowed down to what appears to be a memory leak within the service we use for polling data.**  It appears on each page in which we use the service, but we believe that the symptoms are only an issue on the new screen because of the large number of visual cues (scrolling, updating icons/colors, etc.), many of which have some intensive processing/graphing that runs every cycle when the data is updated, and the fact that no one is likely to have left the other screens up and running for the length of time it may take to start to see symptoms on a less hard-working page.

I took a timeline screenshot in Chrome's developer tools, and this is what it looks like.  It looks similar on each page that uses our polling service. [image: This is what the graph looks like for the actual page.]

I created a [demo of just the polling](https://plnkr.co/edit/MLoENM0Ot3xjLKmQb3Q5?p=preview), and got a similar graph:[image: Demo from plnkr].  It appears a little less severe in the demo, but the pattern is obviously similar, and looks like a memory leak.  **How can we resolve the memory leak and eliminate our other issues?**

Some relevant code:

```
 var reload = function() {
      $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'api.txt',
          timeout: 5000
        })
        .success(function(response) {
          //do stuff
        })
        .error(function(data) {
          //do other stuff
        })
        .finally(function() {
          timer = $timeout(reload, 1000);
        });
    };
```

Comment: check the actual allocations/deallocations - that should tell you *what* is being retained/leaking.

Comment: @DanielA.White  How can I check that?  I've used the Profiles tab and checked snapshots/compared them, but I'm not exactly sure what I'm looking for.  I don't see anything weird, but I've never tried tracking anything like this down before.  How do I know what's supposed to be there and what isn't?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/

Answer (score 0):

are you using closures somewhere in your code?
Since these type of problems occur only while using many closures because that is the place in java script where object is not destroyed, if you use too many closures eventually you will run short of memory.

Comment: I have a line like `$scope.data = response;` in the success function in the `$http` call in `reload()`.  Does that count as a closure, if that's the only time `response` is used?

Comment: that won't count a function inside a function is called as closure.

Comment: Doesn't that mean it would be a closure?  The success function is inside `reload()`, which is what gets called recursively.

Comment: Yes that will be counted and the object created by that method will be retained. You need to make architectural change to your code to make sure that object is being destroyed.

Comment: That's the conclusion we were coming to.  The question I'm asking is how do we do that?  We need to poll the server for our data constantly.